# GitBash blank screen (Windows)

Tags: git, git-bash

[blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmKCj.png)

I entered the following in GitBash and closed the window.

```
echo 'exec /bin/bash --login' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

When I opened it again, there was nothing on it. I can type but I can't delete and it doesn't respond when I press 'enter'.

I uninstalled GitBash and installed it again, but nothing changed.

I opened '.bash_profile', this is how it looked like.

```
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc


if [ -f -/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/mingw64/bin
exec /bin/bash --login
```

Then I deleted line 6-8, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what to do? Thank you.

---

Now I know that I need to delete 'exec /bin/bash --login' in .bash_profile. But I can't open and edit that file now.

Comment: I found that it's actually running every time I open this window. If I use 'ctrl+c' then it'll stop and I can type normally. But how can I keep it from running?

Comment: Why did you create an endless login loop in the first place? Just take it out.

Comment: @tripleee You mean just delete that line? I tried editing .bash_profile, but what I opened was a new file. Then I used 'cat‘ to read .bash_profile, this time it's the old file with that line. But how can I edit the old file?

Comment: ... Please try to construct a minimal example which causes the problem. We really do not want to look through your code base/config files/other source files to find your errors for you :)

Comment: @Kim I think it's because the 'exec /bin/bash --login' in .bash_profile. I need to delete it. But I didn't do that before (when I could edit it), and now I can't open that file.

Comment: The file exists in your home directory regardless of whether you are logged in. Simply run a Windows editor outside of Bash / WSL.

Comment: @tripleeet I think I deleted that line successfully now. Thank you!